# Shader that assigns a different color to different sections of an object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

I have a set of data that has different segments of color e.g.

- item1: [red: 3 units, blue: 5 units, green: 4 units, white: 5 units] (total units 17)
- item2: [red: 4 units, green: 2 units, white: 2 units] (total units 8)
- itemN: ...

I've created objects in Unity that have a size relative to the total number of units e.g.

- item1: ----------------- (17)
- item2: --------          (8)

I would like to color all the objects based on the distribution they have e.g.

- item1: rrr|bbbbb|gggg|wwwww
- item2: rrrr|gg|ww

### Goal

What I hope to do is instantiate one item with a shader on it that takes the number of units of each color and colors segments of it appropriately.

### What I've done so far

I've created m smaller segment-objects, where m is the number of segments per item. I then color these segment-objects appropriately and place them next to each other so they look like one multi-colored item.

### Why I think this is bad

This is a working solution, but there can be thousands of items with thousands of segments and I believe it would vastly increase performance to cut this step out.

I don't have any experience with shaders, but this feels like it should be an already solved problem and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. That said, if an exact solution to my problem doesn't exist, shader code that achieves some similar functionality would be also be perfect.

### Example photo

[image: stacked bar graph]

### Update: Current Shader Code And Explanation

I found a shader online that colored a bar, splitting it in two -> Health and Damages. I then modified that code to have three sections, Health, Damages and Shield to get me closer to my stacked bar type ideal. I also have a C# script that calls

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetFloat("_LifePercent", percent);
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetFloat("_DamagesPercent", percent);
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetFloat("_ShieldPercent", percent);
```

Shader

```
  Shader "Sprites/HealthBar"
    {
      Properties
      {
       [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

       [Header(Life)]_LifeColor ("Main Color", Color) = (0.2,1,0.2,1)
      _LifePercent ("Life Percent", Float) = 1

      [Header(Damages)]_DamagesColor ("Damages color", Color) = (1,1,0,1)
      _DamagesPercent ("Damages Percent", Float) = 0

      [Header(Shield)]_ShieldColor ("Shield color", Color) = (.2, .2, 1, 0)
      _ShieldPercent ("Shield Percent", Float) = 0

  }

  SubShader
  {
      Tags
      { 
          "Queue"="Transparent" 
          "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
          "RenderType"="Transparent" 
          "PreviewType"="Plane"
          "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
      }

      Cull Off
      Lighting Off
      ZWrite Off
      Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

      Pass
      {
      CGPROGRAM
          #pragma vertex vert
          #pragma fragment frag
          #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
          #include "UnityCG.cginc"

          struct appdata_t
          {
              float4 vertex   : POSITION;
              float4 color    : COLOR;
              float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
          };

          struct v2f
          {
              float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
              fixed4 color    : COLOR;
              half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
          };

          fixed4 _LifeColor;
          half _LifePercent;

          fixed4 _DamagesColor;
          half _DamagesPercent;

          fixed4 _ShieldColor;
          half _ShieldPercent;

          v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
          {
              v2f OUT;
              OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
              OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;

              return OUT;
          }

          sampler2D _MainTex;

          fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
          {
              fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord);

              if ( IN.texcoord.x > _LifePercent + _DamagesPercent + _ShieldPercent )
              {
                c.a = 0;
              }
              else if ( IN.texcoord.x < _LifePercent )
              {
                    c *= _LifeColor;
              }

              else if ( IN.texcoord.x < _LifePercent + _ShieldPercent && IN.texcoord.x > _LifePercent )
              {
                    c *= _ShieldColor;
              }
              // if we weren't in the previous two segments we're now in the damages segment
              else
              {
                c *= _DamagesColor;
              }
              c.rgb *= c.a;
              return c;
          }
      ENDCG
      }
  }
```

}

Here's the source of the shader before I modified it:
[unity life bar shader](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1463955/how-can-i-make-the-division-of-the-health-bar-like.html)

The object with the material / shader applied just seems to have the mainTex, with no color anywhere. I also don't fully understand the operations I'm performing on the fixed4 "c". What am I missing?

Comment: You are going to have to provide a lot more information if you want some help with this. What defines a segment? Is it just a piece of surface on the model? Or are these segments arranged on a strip or a grid? I really struggle to picture exactly what it is you are asking for.

Comment: @KalleHalvarsson I've added an image to try to show what I'm going for--My code currently generates 600 distinct game objects for strategy 1. I'm looking to give inputs to a shader and have just one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some more time reading tutorials, specifically from the checkerboard tutorial from unity: [unity vertex/fragment examples](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html)

[image: stacked shader 33-33-34]

[image: stacked shader 20-40-40]

This is what I've got now, it's working pretty much how I expect it to:

```
Shader "Sprites/HealthBar"
{
  Properties
  {
     [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
      [Header(Life)]_LifeColor ("Main Color", Color) = (0.2,1,0.2,1)
      _LifePercent ("Life Percent", Float) = 1

      [Header(Damages)]_DamagesColor ("Damages color", Color) = (1,1,0,1)
      _DamagesPercent ("Damages Percent", Float) = 0

      [Header(Shield)]_ShieldColor ("Shield color", Color) = (.2, .2, 1, 0)
      _ShieldPercent ("Shield Percent", Float) = 0

  }

  SubShader
  {
      Pass
      {
      CGPROGRAM
          #pragma vertex vert
          #pragma fragment frag
          #include "UnityCG.cginc"

          struct v2f
          {
              float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
              float2 uv        : TEXCOORD0;
          };

          fixed4 _LifeColor;
          half _LifePercent;

          fixed4 _DamagesColor;
          half _DamagesPercent;

          fixed4 _ShieldColor;
          half _ShieldPercent;

          v2f vert(float4 pos : POSITION, float2 uv : TEXCOORD0)
          {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
            o.uv = uv * 100;
            return o;
          }

          fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
          {
              float2 c = IN.uv;
              fixed4 cout;

              if (c.y < _LifePercent){
                cout = _LifeColor;
              }
              else if (c.y > _LifePercent && c.y < _DamagesPercent + _LifePercent){
                cout = _DamagesColor;
              }
              else {
                cout = _ShieldColor;
              }
              return cout;

          }
      ENDCG
      }
  }
```

}